# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options' error extracting Google Trends blog post titles using Selenium and BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Right now I have this python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Add this option to avoid sandbox issues
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=US&hl=en-US&category=t')
    scrollable_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body')
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(scrollable_element)
    actions.perform()

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    title_element = soup.find('div', class_='summary-text')
    title = title_element.text.strip() if title_element else None
    print("Title:", title)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

But this is returning an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_titles.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

How do I fix this error and get the blog post titles? Or can someone provide me the Python code for this using another tool or technology? Unfortunately, I am restricted to use Python 2.7.

I can't use Puppeteer because Node.js is not available in my server. Furthermore, I tried PHP Simple HTML DOM and DOMDocument but they are not enough for the google trends dynamic paging and therefore I end up using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [***selenium 4.10.0***](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) project description the minimum supported Python Version is ***3.7***

[image: Python3.7]

You need to upgrade from Python Version ***2.7*** to Python Version ***3.7***